# Disabling 802.11ac/802.11ax only for specific connections?

Tags: linux, networkmanager, iwlwifi

My laptop has an [Intel AX200](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/189347/intel-wi-fi-6-ax200-gig.html) WiFi adapter, which is supported by the `iwlmvm` driver and works in 802.11a/b/g/n/ac/ax modes.

I frequently have to connect to a WiFi network with a very poor signal (about -85 dBm). This network actually *works pretty well* in 802.11n mode, but the connection frequently drops in 802.11ac mode.

As far as I can tell, the [`iwlwifi` module's `disable_11ac` parameter](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg148216.html) (and `disable_11ax` too) *only work at initialization time*. That is, the following works…

```
# modprobe -r iwlwifi && modprobe iwlwifi disable_11ac=1 disable_11ax=1
```

… but the following *does not* work after the module is already installed:

```
# echo 1 | tee /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/disable_{11ac,11ax}
tee: /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/disable_11ac: Permission denied
tee: /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/disable_11ax: Permission denied
1
```

Right now, in order to use this weak network, I need to remove and reinsert the WiFi module to disable 802.11ac/ax… and then afterwards I need to remember to do it again to re-enable them.

**So here's my question:** is there a way to disable 802.11ac/802.11ax (aka VHT/HE) *only for a specific network*? It doesn't appear that I can safely remove and reinsert the module in [NetworkManager dispatcher scripts](https://man.archlinux.org/man/NetworkManager.8#DISPATCHER_SCRIPTS), but perhaps there's a straightforward way to prevent the driver from trying to connect to the specific network in 802.11ac mode.